# Android AndEngine generating random sprites weird probleem

Tags: java, android, andengine

First I start by loading the resources

```
                this.mTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 130, 130);
                this.m1TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p1.png", 0, 0);
                this.m2TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p2.png", 0, 0);
                this.m3TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p3.png", 0, 0);
                this.m4TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p4.png", 0, 0);
                this.mTextureAtlas.load();
```

Then I do

```
int x;
                x = MathUtils.random(1, 4);
                Log.e("euatl", "is" + x);

                p = null;

                if(x == 1){
                    p = new Sprite(mCameraWidth-pX, pY, this.mB1TextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                } else if(x == 2){
                    p = new Sprite(mCameraWidth-pX, pY, this.m2TextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());         
                } else if(x == 3){
                    p = new Sprite(mCameraWidth-pX, pY, this.mB3TextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                } else if(x == 4){
                    p = new Sprite(mCameraWidth-pX, pY, this.m4TextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()); 
                }

                    mScene.attachChild(p);
```

currently always the `p4` sprite spawns, the last one in the `TextureAtlas`. My logcat says that x was random sometimes 1, 2, 3, and 4. But in the phone the sprite is always the last one (`p4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your textures to different locations on your atlas.
Assume that your texture (px.png) size is 130x130:

```
            this.mTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 4 * 130, 130);
            this.m1TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p1.png", 0, 0);
            this.m2TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p2.png", 130, 0);
            this.m3TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p3.png", 260, 0);
            this.m4TextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p4.png", 390, 0);
            this.mTextureAtlas.load();
```

Nicer solution:

```
int textureCount = 4;
TextureRegion[] mTextureRegions = new TextureRegion[textureCount];

for (int i = 0; i < mTextureRegions.length; i++)
   this.mTextureRegions[i] = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTextureAtlas, this, "p" + (i + 1) + ".png", i * 130, 0);
this.mTextureAtlas.load();
```

Comment: Welcome! :) You have got a nicer solution as well.

Comment: BTW, my sprites are 65px but I write 130 cuz I heard that we should multiply the size by two in AndEgine, is that right to be 130 to I do 4 * 65.

Comment: It is not necessary to multiply by two (or anything else).

Comment: so (4*65,65) is fine?

Comment: if your texture size is 65x65, yes! (you can try it! :D)